# SAX Parser XML assistance

Tags: android, saxparser

My XML is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Data>
<Item>
<CategoryId>1</CategoryId>
<Date>20121214</Date>
<Source>mysamplecode@gmail.com</Source>
<ItemDetail>
<quality1>Morning</quality1>
<quality2>12010109Y</quality2>
<quality3>2.00</quality3>
<quality4>7.99</quality4>
 </ItemDetail>
<ItemDetail>
<quality1>Afternoon</quality1>
<quality2>12010109B</quality2>
<quality3>900</quality3>
<quality4>83.50</quality4>
 </ItemDetail>
 <ItemDetail>
 <quality1>Dinner</quality1>
 <quality2>11271581Y</quality2>
  <quality3>16.00</quality3>
  <quality4>8.99</quality4>
  </ItemDetail>
  </Item>


   <Item>
  <CategoryId>2</CategoryId>
  <Date>20121214</Date>
  <Source>code@gmail.com</Source>
  <ItemDetail>
  <quality1>Morning</quality1>
  <quality2>12010109Y</quality2>
 <quality3>2.00</quality3>
  <quality4>7.99</quality4>
 </ItemDetail>
 </Item>


 <Item>
 <CategoryId>3</CategoryId>
<Date>20121214</Date>
 <Source>code@gmail.com</Source>
 <ItemDetail>
  <quality1>Afternoon</quality1>
  <quality2>12010109B</quality2>
  <quality3>900</quality3>
  <quality4>83.50</quality4>
 </ItemDetail>

 </Item>
 </Data>
```

This is my ParserClass

```
    public class OrderXMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {

  boolean currentElement = false;
  String currentValue = "";




 CategoryInfo itemdetail;
 CategoryInfo categoryInfo;
 ArrayList<CategoryInfo> List;




 public ArrayList<CategoryInfo> getList() {
  return List;
}

public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
   Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

  currentElement = true;

 /* if (qName.equals("Data")){
  //List = new ArrayList<CategoryInfo>();

 } */
if (localName.equals("maintag"))
 {}
 else if (qName.equals("Item")) {
  List = new ArrayList<CategoryInfo>();
  ;
 }
 else if (qName.equals("ItemDetail")) {
  categoryInfo = new CategoryInfo();
 }
}

public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
throws SAXException {

  currentElement = false;

 if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("CategoryId"))
    {
  categoryInfo.setCategoryId(currentValue.trim());
  listId = currentValue.trim();
    }
 else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Date"))
  {//categoryInfo.setDate(currentValue.trim());
  date = currentValue.trim();}
 else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Source"))
  {//categoryInfo.setSource(currentValue.trim());
    source = currentValue.trim();}

 else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("quality1"))
  categoryInfo.setQuality1(currentValue.trim());
 else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("quality2"))
  categoryInfo.setQuality2(currentValue.trim());
else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("quality3"))
  categoryInfo.setQuality3(currentValue.trim());
 else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("quality4"))
  categoryInfo.setQuality4(currentValue.trim());
 else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("ItemDetail"))
  List.add(categoryInfo);

 currentValue = "";
 }

  public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
throws SAXException {

 if (currentElement) {
    currentValue = currentValue + new String(ch, start, length);
 }

   }

  }
```

I don't think I have it correctly parsing for my XML I'm made up.  SO when I start it Data is just the container element so I dont' know how to just read that and go to next element each item to my Arraylist which goes into the Class CateogoryInfo that stores each item and info.   Each one has header and item detail or multiple item detail.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

         XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
         String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
         Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

         NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("Item");
         // looping through all item nodes <item>
         for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
             // creating new HashMap
             HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
             Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
             // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
             map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, "CategoryId"));
             map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, "Source"));

                NodeList n2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("ItemDetail");
          for (int i = 0; i < n2.getLength(); i++) {
             map.put(KEY_COST, "Rs." + parser.getValue(e, "quality1"));
             map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, "quality2"));
           }
             // adding HashList to ArrayList
             menuItems.add(map);
         }
```

Use like this.. i think your solution would be done here..